# Does occupation show on a one visa affect your chances of getting visa for another country?

Tags: visas, study, belgium, pakistani-citizens, uae

I am about to finish my Bachelors in Engineering from Pakistan, my home country. I have received a full scholarship for Master's program in Belgium.

I have a UAE residence visa that shows an occupation as private driver, although I have never worked as a driver. I kept the UAE permanent visa because my family lives there, and it facilitates traveling back and forth from Pakistan.

Would having a visa on my passsport as a private driver affect my chances of getting a Belgian visa. Would it make any difference if I apply from UAE or from Pakistan?

Answer (score 2):

It will not affect your current chances of having a visa, it's just a job, they will only care about your reason for applying for your current visa, and you provide the needed documents to support that and that's what the decision is based on, history only matters in cases like criminal activity etc, not normal job history.